# ¡Acceso Prohibido! error 403

Tags: php, apache

Descargué un código de Github escrito en php, y al querer correrlo en localhost, me lanza el siguiente mensaje:

```
**¡Acceso prohibido!**
**Usted no tiene permiso para acceder al objeto solicitado. El objeto está protegido contra lectura o el servidor no puede leerlo.
Si usted cree que esto es un error del servidor, por favor comuníqueselo al administrador del portal**

**Error 403**
localhost
Apache/2.4.33 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2n PHP/7.2.4 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3**
```

He buscado por todos lados, pero no encuentro solución. ¿Alguien sabe porqué pasa y cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Gracias.

Comment: Ya he clonado varios proyectos y siempre sale el mismo mensaje.

Comment: cual es la url del proyecto ?

Answer (score 1):

Comprueba los permisos y el propietario de los archivos del proyecto. Muchas veces el error 403 se debe a que el servidor web no tiene permisos suficientes para leer el archivo y por lo tanto no puede ejecutar el código que hay dentro.

Si tienes acceso SSH puedes probar con:

```
chmod 755 $(find /home/villamzr/public_html -type d)
chmod 644 $(find /home/villamzr/public_html -type f)
```

Por supuesto, cambia `/home/villamzr/public_html` por la ruta a tu proyecto.